# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. This is the error which its showing on datakey

Tags: asp.net

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. This is the error which its showing on datakey

[image]

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select SubMenu_id from SubmenuRec where Menu_id in ('" + strParam + "')";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(ds);
    for (int j = 0; j <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; j++)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            CheckBox CheckBox1;
            CheckBox1 = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect");
            //if (CheckBox1.Checked && String = "strConnString")
            string showId = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString();

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == showId)
            {
                //check box checked and correct string

                CheckBox1.Checked = true;
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here in  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == showId) it should be  if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() == showId)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change code from below to
     if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[j][0].ToString() == showId)

```
 if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() == showId)
```

because value of j is length of ds.Tables[0] +1 so it giving you error.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your reply but the error is showing itself in string showId = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[i].Value.ToString();

Comment: if you have only one DataKey in your Gridview then you need to use below string showId = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[0].Value.ToString(); because DataKeys is array of keys that we have set for Gridview try this.

Comment: not working..its showing another error..i can use only one datakey

Comment: have you set DataKeyNames in Gridview from aspx page?

Comment: no..is there any need to set datakeyname..because its a method

Comment: from aspx page where you have code for GridView there is property DataKeyNames="" where you have to set Column name that you want to use as DataKey and want to get name in code behind, then you can get value of that

Comment: hey thank you so much :)... but now another error is coming.....

DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'SubMenu_id Submenu_name'.

Comment: can you please post your aspx code and Grid data binding code